# How To convert 1D array to 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
string snacks="Chocolate,Alwa,Samosa,Channa";
```

I need this as array like:

`snacks= {"Chocolate,Alwa" , "Samosa,Channa"};` in C#.

Could anyone pls Suggest the way to find my snacks

Comment: Do you want a two-dimensional array, a jagged array, or a dictionary of arrays?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this. Can you provide some logic as to how you're grouping things? Also, please provide some code to show what you've tried.

Comment: two-dimensional array :)

Comment: First hit on google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx so that you can get the logic and do your implementation.

Comment: yes gadria. Thanks ..

Comment: My need is 
 string[] SingleSnacks= { "Chocolate","Alwa","Samosa","Channa"};
to convert as
string[,] DoubleSnacks= {
                                             {"Chocolate,Alwa" },
                                             { "Samosa,Channa"}
                                      };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string snack2[][]=new string[Math.Round(snacks.Length/2)][2];
        int cnt=0;
        for(int i=0;i<Math.Round(snacks.Length/2);i++)
        {
             for (int j=0;j<2;j++)
             {
                 snacks2[i][j]=snack[cnt++];
             }
        }
```

Comment: The OP has explicitly asked for a 2D array NOT a jagged array.

Comment: Thanks Kartal. It works fine :)

Comment: My pleasure Prakash.